# ListView not updating row views

Tags: android, android-listview, customization

I have created a custom ListView using ArrayAdapter. ListView's row has two views, one is the main view & other is hidden & it appears when a TextView on main view is clicked.

For showing data on rows I have a created an Object. I am facing some issues in my ListView.

1. This issue occurs some time. Whenever I delete an item from ListView, I can see the item is deleted from my ArrayList & then I call notifyDataSetChanged. The issue is this the ListView still shows the deleted row but its not clickable(only view is there). Only other rows are clickable which are not deleted yet. Check image 1.

[image: Issue 1]

2. I have used a flag in my Object to hide/show the hidden view. But sometimes it doesn't appear well. Check image 2 [image: Issue 2]
3. Sometimes after hiding the hidden view it still shows below the main view. Check image 3 [image: Issue 3]

Please help me out in this.

```
class ShippingAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ShippingOption>
    {
        ShippingAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ShippingOption> list)
        {
            super(context, R.layout.row_shipping, R.id.row_shipping_tv_product_name, list);
        }

        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            ShippingViewHolder holder = (ShippingViewHolder) row.getTag();
            if (holder == null)
            {
                holder = new ShippingViewHolder(row);
                row.setTag(holder);
            }

            final ShippingOption shippingOption = getShippingOption(position);

            holder.tvRemove.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    showRemoveDialog(shippingOption.getProductId(), position);
                }
            });
            holder.tvProductName.setText(shippingOption.getProductName());
            imageLoader.DisplayImage(shippingOption.getProductImageUrl(), holder.ivProduct);

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapterShippingOption = createAdapter(holder.spinnerShippingOption, shippingOption.getListShipping(), R.layout.spinner_textview_blue);
            holder.spinnerShippingOption.setSelection(adapterShippingOption.getPosition(shippingOption.getSelectedOption()));
            if (shippingOption.getSelectedOption().equals(Constants.PICK_UP_AT_STORE))
            {
                HashMap<String, Integer> mapPickupAddress = shippingOption.getMapPickupAddress();
                Collection<String> collection = mapPickupAddress.keySet();
                ArrayList<String> listAddress = new ArrayList<String>();
                listAddress.addAll(collection);

                ArrayAdapter<String> adapterAddress = createAdapter(holder.spinnerAddress, listAddress, R.layout.spinner_textview_blue_small);
                holder.spinnerAddress.setSelection(adapterAddress.getPosition(shippingOption.getSelectedAddress()));
                holder.relativeAddress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.spinnerAddress.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
                    {
                        String selectedAddress = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

                        String oldAddress = shippingOption.getSelectedAddress();
                        shippingOption.setSelectedAddress(selectedAddress);
                        if (oldAddress == null || !oldAddress.equals(selectedAddress))
                            notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0)
                    {
                    }
                });
            } else
            {
                holder.relativeAddress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            holder.spinnerShippingOption.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
                {
                    String selectedOption = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                    // if (!selectedOption.equals(Constants.FREE_SHIPPING))
                    // {
                    String oldOption = shippingOption.getSelectedOption();
                    shippingOption.setSelectedOption(selectedOption);
                    if (!oldOption.equals(selectedOption))
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    // }
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent)
                {
                }
            });
            holder.relativeLayoutGift.setVisibility(shippingOption.isGiftDetailsVisible() ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
            if (shippingOption.isGiftWrapAvailable())
            {
                imageLoader.DisplayImage(shippingOption.getGiftImageUrl(), holder.ivGift);
                holder.layoutGift.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                ArrayList<String> listGift = new ArrayList<String>();
                listGift.add("Not a Gift");
                listGift.add("Yes it's a Gift $" + shippingOption.getGiftServiceCharge());
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapterGift = createAdapter(holder.spinnerGift, listGift, R.layout.spinner_textview_blue);

                holder.tvGiftDetails.setVisibility(shippingOption.getSelectedGiftOption().equals("Not a Gift") ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
                holder.spinnerGift.setSelection(adapterGift.getPosition(shippingOption.getSelectedGiftOption()));
                holder.spinnerGift.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
                    {
                        String selectedOption = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                        String oldOption = shippingOption.getSelectedGiftOption();
                        shippingOption.setSelectedGiftOption(selectedOption);

                        if (!oldOption.equals(selectedOption))
                            notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent)
                    {
                    }
                });

                holder.tvGiftDetails.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v)
                    {
                        shippingOption.setGiftDetailsVisible(true);
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });

                holder.relativeGiftDetails.setVisibility(shippingOption.isGiftDetailsVisible() ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
                holder.relativeLayoutGift.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v)
                    {
                    }
                });

                holder.btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v)
                    {
                        shippingOption.setGiftDetailsVisible(false);
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });

                holder.btnClose.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v)
                    {
                        shippingOption.setGiftDetailsVisible(false);
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });

                final EditText editLocal = holder.editGiftMessage;

                holder.btnApply.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v)
                    {
                        String message = editLocal.getText().toString();
                        shippingOption.setGiftMessageApplied(true);
                        shippingOption.setGiftMessage(message);
                        shippingOption.setGiftDetailsVisible(false);
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });

                holder.editGiftMessage.setText(shippingOption.getGiftMessage());

                holder.editGiftMessage.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
                    {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
                    {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
                    {
                    }
                });

            } else
            {
                holder.layoutGift.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.relativeGiftDetails.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            return row;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Okay, I am able to solve my 1st & 3rd issue. In my layout I had set height of ListView as WRAP_CONTENT but after changing to MATCH_PARENT it is working fine. It may be because in case of WRAP_CONTENT the ListView was not able to get enough space to scroll & update, Not Sure :).
But 2nd issue is still there.

Answer (score 1):

Here i am going to demonstrate for one view tagging.

```
        ShippingViewHolder holder;
        if (holder == null)
        {
            holder = new ShippingViewHolder(row);
            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        holder = (ShippingViewHolder) row.getTag();
        ShippingOption shippingOption = getShippingOption(position);
        holder.tvRemove.setTag(shippingOption);
        holder.tvRemove.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {

                ShippingOption shippingOption1 =(ShippingOption) v.getTag();

                int pos = getPosition(shippingOption1); // this is the function that will return you the postion of your object from your passed list of object; write it your self.
                showRemoveDialog(shippingOption1.getProductId(), pos);
            }
        });
```

Comment: show me your adapter 
i think you are not using tagging in adapter

Comment: place a check if project property is gone gone then hide all view of that associate with this object but use tag for all associate views like i mentioned.

Comment: remove object from your list. then call notifyDataSetChanged().
again set adapter form showremove dialog.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63153/discussion-between-ab1209-and-danial-hussain).